# Map and Sort in one iteration in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, sorting

Is it possible to map an array to a new array and to sort it at the same time without iterating twice (once for the map on the first array and once for the sort on the second array)? I've been trying to sort it with an anonymous function when using the map method like this:

```
var arr=[4,2,20,44,6];
var arr2=arr.map(function(item, index, array){
    if(index==array.length-1 || item==array[index+1]){
        return item;
    }
    else if((item-array[index+1])<0){
        return item;
    }
    else if((item-array[index+1])>0){
        return array[index+1];
    }
});
console.log(arr2);
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Am I way off base here in how I'm trying to implement this, or is there just a problem with my code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorting generally takes more than one iteration by itself. It's almost certainly O(n log n) for the average case (the algorithm isn't specified by ECMAScript, but that's the best you can do with a comparison sort), so there's not much point in doing both at the same time.

You can chain them into one expression though, since `sort` returns the array itself:

```
function order(a, b) {
    return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
}
var arr2 = arr.map(function(item) { ... }).sort(order);
```